# Edge alternative solution to capturing wheel/mousewheel event when using trackpad

Tags: javascript, events, microsoft-edge

There's a bug on Edge that when you're using a precision trackpad the wheel/mousehweel event doesn't fire.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7134034/

The issue appears as Fixed but hasn't been fixed yet (tested on Lenovo notebook and Surface Pro with Edge last version)

Is there any way to capture this event? I tried using an overlay element and capture the scroll event and it works but you can't click anything on the page because of that overlay, and givin't it pointer-events: none makes disables the scroll event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the open issue you pointed, the Microsoft Edge Team said that the issue has been solved by their implementation of PTP Pointer Events as outlined in [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/12/07/better-precision-touchpad-experience-ptp-pointer-events/).

> In HTML, add the touch-action CSS property to your target element to prevent the browser from executing its default touch behavior in response to gestures:

```
<canvas height=400 width=400 id="canvas" style="touch-action: none;"></canvas>
```

> In JavaScript, attach a Pointer Event listener to your target element. You can determine the type of pointer that caused the handler to be invoked using the pointerType property of the event object passed into the event listener callback:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('pointermove', function(event) {
    console.log('pointermove!');
});
```

You could refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Using_Pointer_Events) for more detailed information about Point Events.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up using pointermove, for anyone interested, you there's a property on the event called pointerType that is either "touch" or "mouse", touch only when using two fingers, so then I used the pageY property with a delta to check if the mouse was being moved up or down when the pointerType is touch. Kind of tricky but it does the job!

**Important: the `touch-action` should be set to none otherwise it won't work, however this disables the option to swipe left or right with two fingers to navigate back and forth between history.**